# Group and combine items of multiple-column lists with itertools/more-itertools in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

This code:

```
from itertools import groupby, count 
L = [38, 98, 110, 111, 112, 120, 121, 898] 
groups = groupby(L, key=lambda item, c=count():item-next(c))
tmp = [list(g) for k, g in groups]
```

Takes `[38, 98, 110, 111, 112, 120, 121, 898]` , groups it by consecutive numbers and merge them with this final output:

```
['38', '98', '110,112', '120,121', '898']
```

How can the same be done with a list of lists with multiple columns, like this list below where you can group them by name and the consecution of its second column value and then merge.

In other words, this data:

```
L= [
['Italy','1','3']
['Italy','2','1'],
['Spain','4','2'],
['Spain','5','8'],
['Italy','3','10'],
['Spain','6','4'],
['France','5','3'],
['Spain','20','2']]
```

should give the following output:

```
[['Italy','1-2-3','3-1-10'],
['France','5','3'],
['Spain','4-5-6','2-8-4'],
['Spain','20','2']]
```

Should **more-itertools** be more appropriate for this task?

Group and combine items of multiple-column lists with itertools/more-itertools in Python

Comment: Why there are 2 Spains in your result but one Italy?

Comment: @Kasramvd Second column values must be consecutive ints.

Comment: @Kasramvd Because the first Spain has consecutive numbers 4,5,6 and the second Spain is isolated with a 20. Italy has no isolated items.

Comment: @mistervela isolated items means.??

Comment: @Pradam Isolated, I'm referring to the ones that don't have consecutive values, like ['Spain', '20', '2'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially the same grouping technique, but rather than using `itertools.count` it uses `enumerate` to produce the indices.

First, we sort the data so that all items for a given country are grouped together, and the data is sorted. Then we use `groupby` to make a group for each country. Then we use `groupby` in the inner loop to group together the consecutive data for each country. Finally, we use `zip` & `.join` to re-arrange the data into the desired output format.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [
    ['Italy','1','3'],
    ['Italy','2','1'],
    ['Spain','4','2'],
    ['Spain','5','8'],
    ['Italy','3','10'],
    ['Spain','6','4'],
    ['France','5','3'],
    ['Spain','20','2'],
]

newlst = [[country] + ['-'.join(s) for s in zip(*[v[1][1:] for v in g])]
    for country, u in groupby(sorted(lst), itemgetter(0))
        for _, g in groupby(enumerate(u), lambda t: int(t[1][1]) - t[0])]

for row in newlst:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
['France', '5', '3']
['Italy', '1-2-3', '3-1-10']
['Spain', '20', '2']
['Spain', '4-5-6', '2-8-4']
```

I admit that `lambda` is a bit cryptic; it'd probably better to use a proper `def` function instead. I'll add that here in a few minutes.

---

Here's the same thing using a much more readable key function.

```
def keyfunc(t):
    # Unpack the index and data
    i, data = t
    # Get the 2nd column from the data, as an integer
    val = int(data[1])
    # The difference between val & i is constant in a consecutive group
    return val - i

newlst = [[country] + ['-'.join(s) for s in zip(*[v[1][1:] for v in g])]
    for country, u in groupby(sorted(lst), itemgetter(0))
        for _, g in groupby(enumerate(u), keyfunc)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can build up on the same recipe and modify the lambda function to include the first item(country) from each row as well. Secondly, you need to sort the list first based on the last occurrence of the country in the list.

```
from itertools import groupby, count


L = [
    ['Italy', '1', '3'],
    ['Italy', '2', '1'],
    ['Spain', '4', '2'],
    ['Spain', '5', '8'],
    ['Italy', '3', '10'],
    ['Spain', '6', '4'],
    ['France', '5', '3'],
    ['Spain', '20', '2']]


indices = {row[0]: i for i, row in enumerate(L)}
sorted_l = sorted(L, key=lambda row: indices[row[0]])
groups = groupby(
    sorted_l,
    lambda item, c=count(): [item[0], int(item[1]) - next(c)]
)
for k, g in groups:
    print [k[0]] + ['-'.join(x) for x in zip(*(x[1:] for x in g))]
```

## Output:

```
['Italy', '1-2-3', '3-1-10']
['France', '5', '3']
['Spain', '4-5-6', '2-8-4']
['Spain', '20', '2']
```

Comment: I am little confused with `int(item[1]) - next(c)` in `groupby` key. Is this going to group all elements that have similar difference?

Comment: @bro-grammer Yes, all elements with similar first item(country) and consecutive second item.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `itertools.groupby` that requires multiple sorting, checking, etc. Here is an algorithmically optimized approach using dictionaries:

```
d = {}
flag = False
for country, i, j in L:
    temp = 1
    try:
        item = int(i)
        for counter, recs in  d[country].items():
            temp += 1
            last = int(recs[-1][0])
            if item in {last - 1, last, last + 1}:
                recs.append([i, j])
                recs.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
                flag = True
                break
        if flag:
            flag = False
            continue
        else:
            d[country][temp] = [[i, j]]
    except KeyError:
        d[country] = {}
        d[country][1] = [[i, j]]
```

Demo on a more complex example:

```
L = [['Italy', '1', '3'],
 ['Italy', '2', '1'],
 ['Spain', '4', '2'],
 ['Spain', '5', '8'],
 ['Italy', '3', '10'],
 ['Spain', '6', '4'],
 ['France', '5', '3'],
 ['Spain', '20', '2'],
 ['France', '5', '44'],
 ['France', '9', '3'],
 ['Italy', '3', '10'],
 ['Italy', '5', '17'],
 ['Italy', '4', '13'],]

{'France': {1: [['5', '3'], ['5', '44']], 2: [['9', '3']]},
 'Spain': {1: [['4', '2'], ['5', '8'], ['6', '4']], 2: [['20', '2']]},
 'Italy': {1: [['1', '3'], ['2', '1'], ['3', '10'], ['3', '10'], ['4', '13']], 2: [['5', '17']]}}

# You can then produce the results in your intended format as below:
for country, recs in d.items():
    for rec in recs.values():
        i, j = zip(*rec)
        print([country, '-'.join(i), '-'.join(j)])

['France', '5-5', '3-44']
['France', '9', '3']
['Italy', '1-2-3-3-4', '3-1-10-10-13']
['Italy', '5', '17']
['Spain', '4-5-6', '2-8-4']
['Spain', '20', '2']
```

Comment: Nice idea but it might fail if multiple countries have the same second value. You could sort by name (but would lose the order then) hm

Comment: @Banana Countries with same second items should be considered as consecutive. It they're not you can't decided which one should be placed in the loop.

Comment: I don't think thats what I mean. I meant that if you had '['Spain','2','4']' in the list, then Italys consecutive elements are not grouped as such. Also OP doesn't want spain to be grouped as 6 and 20 are not consecutive

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import namedtuple
country = namedtuple('country','name score1 score2')
master_dict = {}
isolated_dict = {}
for val in L:
    data = country(*val)
    name = data.name
    if name in master_dict:
        local_data = master_dict[name]
        if (int(local_data[1][-1]) + 1) == int(data.score1):
            local_data[1] += '-' + data.score1
            local_data[2] += '-' + data.score2
        else:
            if name in isolated_dict:
                another_local_data = isolated_dict[name]
                another_local_data[1] += '-' + data.score1
                another_local_data[2] += '-' + data.score2
            else:
                isolated_dict[name] = [name,data.score1,data.score2]
    else:
        master_dict.setdefault(name, [name,data.score1,data.score2])
country_data = list(master_dict.values())+list(isolated_dict.values())
print(country_data)

>>>[['Italy', '1-2-3', '3-1-10'],
 ['Spain', '4-5-6', '2-8-4'],
 ['France', '5', '3'],
 ['Spain', '20', '2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how one might use [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools), a third-party library of itertools-like recipes.

[`more_itertools.consecutive_groups`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups) can group consecutive items by some condition.

**Given**

```
import collections as ct

import more_itertools as mit


lst = [
    ['Italy',  '1', '3'],
    ['Italy',  '2', '1'],
    ['Spain',  '4', '2'],
    ['Spain',  '5', '8'],
    ['Italy',  '3', '10'],
    ['Spain',  '6', '4'],
    ['France', '5', '3'],
    ['Spain', '20', '2']
]
```

**Code**

Pre-process data into a dictionary for fast, flexible lookups:

```
dd = ct.defaultdict(list)
for row in lst:
    dd[row[0]].append(row[1:])
dd
```

*Intermediate Output*

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'France': [['5', '3']],
             'Italy': [['1', '3'], ['2', '1'], ['3', '10']],
             'Spain': [['4', '2'], ['5', '8'], ['6', '4'], ['20', '2']]})
```

Now build whatever output you wish:

```
result = []
for k, v in dd.items():
    cols = [[int(item) for item in col] for col in zip(*v)]
    grouped_rows = [list(c) for c in mit.consecutive_groups(zip(*cols), lambda x: x[0])]
    grouped_cols = [["-".join(map(str, c)) for c in zip(*grp)] for grp in grouped_rows]
    for grp in grouped_cols:
        result.append([k, *grp])        

result
```

*Final Output*

```
[['Italy', '1-2-3', '3-1-10'],
 ['Spain', '4-5-6', '2-8-4'],
 ['Spain', '20', '2'],
 ['France', '5', '3']]
```

---

**Details**

- We build a lookup dict of (country, row(s)) key-value pairs.
- Row values are converted to integer columns.
- Columns are made by zipping rows, which is passed to `more_itertools.consecutive_groups`.  In return are groups of rows based on your condition (here, it is based on the first column `lambda x: x[0]` the dictionary values `dd`.  This is equivalent to the OP's "second column").
- We rejoin rows as groups of stringed columns.
- Each iterated item is appended to the resulting list.

Note: resulting order was not specified, but you can sort the output however you wish using `sorted()` and a key function.  In Python 3.6, insertion order is preserved in the dictionary, creating reproducible dictionaries.

Comment: In your code where are you sorting by the 2nd column of the list? i don't see something like x[1]

Comment: Yes, see `mit.consecutive_groups(zip(*cols), lambda x: x[0])`.  This is grouping by your "second column", which is the first column of the `dd` dictionary.  See edits.