# How to groupby one column in ndarray but then print whole rows

Tags: python, arrays

I've got an array that looks like:

```
sna = 
[[      5376       5562 1487764215          7]
 [      5000       5101 1487764215          8]
 [      3305       3510 1487764215          9]
 [      3511       3642 1487764240          3]
 [      9748      10320 1487764240          4]
 [      9202       9747 1487764260          7]
 [      6793       7173 1487764260         14]...]
```

I want to group those that have consecutive numbers in col3 and same number in col2 together.

I've got something that groups them together correctly but only prints out col4:

```
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(sna[:,3]), lambda(i, x): i-x):
    print map(itemgetter(1), g)
```

With this method is it even possible to print out the whole rows, or do I need to go about this some other way?

The output I'm looking for is something like this:

```
[[      5376       5562 1487764215          7]
 [      5000       5101 1487764215          8]
 [      3305       3510 1487764215          9]]
[[      3511       3642 1487764240          3]
 [      9748      10320 1487764240          4]]
```

Comment: You're looking for something like this: [Group and combine items of multiple-column lists with itertools/more-itertools in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48664043/846892)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is having the same problem, I ended up putting it into a panda dataframe:

```
columns = ['one','two','three','four']
df = pd.DataFrame(sna,columns=columns)
kar = []
[[kar.append(h) for m,h in g.groupby(g['four'] - 
np.arange(g.shape[0])) if len(h) > 1] for k,g in 
df.groupby(df['three'])]
```